# General term of a sequence and its limit.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, radicals

Having a sequence $\;\sqrt[3]5\;,\;\sqrt[3]{5\sqrt[3]5}\;,\;\sqrt[3]{5\sqrt[3]{5\sqrt[3]5}}\;,\;\ldots\;,\;$ what could be the general term and its limit ?

Note that the second term is cube root of $5$ and inside that there is cube root of $5$ again and the third term is cube root of $5$ and two cube root of $5$ inside the outer cube root of $5$.

I tried to define it recursively as

$c_{n+1}=\sqrt[3]{5c_n}\;$ where $\;c_1=\sqrt[3]5\;.$

Comment: Without more context, $C_{n+1}=\sqrt[3]{5 \cdot C_n}$ with $C_1=\sqrt[3]{5}$ is a perfectly reasonable sequence which fits the currently visible pattern.  Now... as for finding the limit, you could try to first show that the sequence is strictly increasing and bounded by induction and thus must converge via monotone convergence theorem, and then assume that eventually two successive terms are effectively "equal".  Letting $\sqrt[3]{5\sqrt[3]{5\sqrt[3]{5\cdots}}} = C$, we would have $C = \sqrt[3]{5C}$ and you can use algebra to try to solve for $C$.

Answer (score 7):

Observe the pattern that, if the $n$th term of the sequence is denoted $c_n$, then

$$c_n = 5^{1/3 + (1/3)^2 + (1/3)^3 + \cdots + (1/3)^n}$$

To see this, notice that, for instance:

\begin{align*}
c_2 &= \sqrt[3]{ 5 \sqrt[3] 5} = \left( 5 \cdot 5^{1/3} \right)^{1/3} = 5^{1/3} \cdot 5^{1/3^2} = 5^{1/3 + 1/3^2} \\
c_3 &= \sqrt[3]{ 5 \sqrt[3]{5\sqrt[3]{5}}} = \left( 5 \cdot \left(5 \cdot 5^{1/3}\right)^{1/3} \right)^{1/3} = 5^{1/3} \cdot 5^{1/3^2} \cdot 5^{1/3^3} = 5^{1/3 + 1/3^2 + 1/3^3} \\
\end{align*}

and so on and so forth. The exponent of $c_n$ is a geometric series with ratio $1/3$ (just starting at $1/3$ and not $1$), and thus

\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^n \left( \frac 1 3 \right)^k 
&= \frac{(1/3)^{n+1} - 1}{1/3 - 1} - 1\\
&= \left( -\frac 3 2 \right)\cdot \frac{1}{3^{n+1}} - \left( -\frac 3 2 \right)\cdot1 - 1\\
&= \frac 1 2 \left( 1 - \frac{1}{3^n} \right)
\end{align*}

and so

$$c_n = 5^{(1 - 3^{-n})/2}$$

Taking the limit $n \to \infty$ is trivial enough, and gives the limit $c_n \to 5^{1/2} = \sqrt 5$.

Comment: I think you meant $\sqrt5$, not $\sqrt2$, at the end

Comment: Yeah, clearly I need to take some time to wake up. But I think everything's right now. Sorry for the trouble.